# Trying to partition to remove rows where two columns don't match sql

Tags: group-by, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, partitioning

How can I filter out rows within a group that do not have matching values in two columns?

I have a table A like:

| CODE | US_ID | US_PRICE | NON_US_ID | NON_US_PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5109 | 57 | 10 | 75 | 10 |
| 0206 | 85 | 11 | 58 | 11 |
| 0206 | 85 | 15 | 33 | 14 |
| 0206 | 85 | 41 | 22 | 70 |
| T100 | 20 | 10 | 49 | NULL |
| T100 | 20 | 38 | 64 | 38 |

Within each CODE group, I want to check whether `US_PRICE = NON_US_PRICE` and remove that row from the resulting table.

I tried:

```
SELECT *,
CASE WHEN US_PRICE != NON_US_PRICE OVER (PARTITION BY CODE) END
FROM A;
```

but I think I am missing something when I try to partition by CODE.
I want the resulting table to look like

| CODE | US_ID | US_PRICE | NON_US_ID | NON_US_PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0206 | 85 | 15 | 33 | 14 |
| 0206 | 85 | 41 | 22 | 70 |
| T100 | 20 | 10 | 49 | NULL |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For provided sample, simple WHERE clause could produce such result:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE US_PRICE IS DISTINCT FROM NON_US_PRICE;
```

`IS DISTINCT FROM` handles NULLs comparing to `!=` operator.

Comment: This is missing the `Within each CODE group` part of the requirement though.

Comment: @GregPavlik The group part is vague in my opinion. as there is no example in provided sample.   Though it could be extended with  `QUALIFY NOT ARRAY_CONTAINS(US_PRICE ::VARIANT, ARRAY_AGG(NON_US_PRICE) OVER(PARTITION BY  CODE) )`